# I've been trying all day to try and count a users characters and print them to the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was just trying to see if there was any way to calculate how many characters a user can type minus the blanks and I can't seem to figure it out. What I've recently tried is down below.

I created a textField where a user can enter their characters. Next, I try to do something I read about printing it like this... txtName.text!.count

Can someone please help?

```
import SwiftUI

import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your text here", text: $userInput)

        print($userInput.text.count)

    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by blanks? Are blanks spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to print in a body structure because it requires some view. I added a `VStack` so I can have multiple `Views` and added a `Text` so I can display the number of characters.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter your text here", text: $userInput)

            Text("\(userInput.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this on a  TextFieldWrapperView and it didn't work. Do you know why it would't? Or how I could make this work on a TextFieldWrapper?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case it can be as following

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var userInput: String = ""
    var body: some View {
       print(userInput.count)
       return TextField("Enter your text here", text: $userInput)
    }
}
```